# Multicores and mulithreads

Tags: multithreading, hardware

If a software devoloped with multi threading , Is it true that multicore processor executes that software efficiently by using software threads of operating system i.e when i create multiple threads in java those threads are exicuted simultineously by multicore processor by linking these java threads with software threads of OS ?

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked here.

Comment: The question remains unclear, and has almost certainly been asked and answered many times already. Try [http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=thread+core+multi](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=thread+core+multi) or similar searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It varies with the JVM implementation and OS, but when coding you should take a defensive position and assume that multiple threads will be active at the same time.

Pragmactically, you will see good use of multiple cores on many major platforms. There's quite a bit of cleverness in commerical JVMs now to do garbage collection so as to reduce the impact of that on muti-core platforms.